# Is copying and pasting a sort of object embedding?

Tags: terminology

If I copy a picture and paste it into Microsoft Word, would there be the difference if I embedded the same picture into another Word file ? Are they both object embedding?(As the object is saved in the document?)

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a question about computer science.  Any community votes?   Questions about how a specific software tool or product work are normally outside of the scope of this site.

Comment: (I don't want to imagine a definition of *copy and paste* outside a given tool(-set).)